# how to use loginRedirect with Vuejs and Msal

Tags: javascript, azure, vuejs3, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm currently working on integrating Azure authorization into my Vue.js Single Page Application (SPA) using the msal.js package.
My goal is to find an elegant way to save the accessToken to localStorage.
Since it's an SPA, I acquire the token when the application loads for the first time. After the redirect, I have to refresh the page for the token acquisition function to run.

Many websites use a middle page that shows a countdown (e.g., "You will be redirected in 5, 4, 3, 2, 1...") to provide a better user experience.
I want to implement something similar to enhance the UX feeling for the user. I'm trying to use the loginRedirect function with localStorage configured.

However, I'm facing a few issues:

First, for some reason, the cache items are saved in sessionStorage instead of localStorage as I have configured. I'm not sure why this is happening. Do you have any ideas?

Second, on the redirect page, when I call msalInstance.getAllAccounts(), it returns an empty list. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the flow.

Here's the relevant code:

In Mystore.ts:

```
const MSAL_CONFIG = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "clientid",
    authority: "authorities.signIn",
    knownAuthorities: [...knownAuthorities],
    redirectUri: "http:://localhost:3000/redirect-page",
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
};

initMsalInstance() {
  this.msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(MSAL_CONFIG);
},

openLoginRedirect() {
  this.initMsalInstance();
  this.msalInstance.loginRedirect();
},

async fetchAccessToken() {
  // Get all accounts from the cache
  const accounts = this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
  // Perform some work if accounts are found, such as getting the token and saving it...
}
```

I'm not using promises as the documentation states that it's not recommended in this case:

```
IMPORTANT: It is NOT recommended to have code that is dependent on the resolution of the Promise. This function will navigate away from the current browser window. It currently returns a Promise in order to reflect the asynchronous nature of the code running in this function.
```

Then, the page redirects to the redirect page in order to fetch the token.

In the redirect page:

```
<template>
  <div>You will be redirected in 5 seconds...</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue";
import { mystore } from "@/store";
import router from "@/router";

onBeforeMount(async () => {
  await mystore.fetchAccessToken();
  router.push({ name: "shop-home-page" });
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

The redirect page calls fetchAccessToken, but this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts() always returns 0. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Does my flow look okay? Is there something different I should be doing? I prefer not to use promises with loginRedirect or loginPopup in MSAL as it's not recommended.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The page that you are redirected to needs to [handle the redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#sign-in-with-redirect) as shown in the documentation.

Since the page redirects, instead of relying on the promise, the SDK uses browser storage to keep track of the interaction.

The SDK needs to handle it before you can access the account and access token. Also, note that it is recommended to simply use the `acquireTokenSilent` method to get the token instead of handling the caching yourself.

Check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript2#acquire-a-token-with-a-redirect) on how you can use it along with handling redirect when needed.